# Failed while adding Dynamic webmodule in eclipse : nullpointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add web module in jbpm project.But its giving me an error `failed while installing Dynamic web module 3.0 - java.lang.NullpointerException.

My jdk version is 1.7_09 and eclipse version is kepler.So what is wrong to get this error.

Stacktrace.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2014-02-19 14:41:25.210
!MESSAGE Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 3.0.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.WebAnnotationReader.analyzeCompilationUnit(WebAnnotationReader.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.WebAnnotationReader.loadModel(WebAnnotationReader.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractAnnotationModelProvider.getConcreteModel(AbstractAnnotationModelProvider.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractAnnotationModelProvider.getModelObject(AbstractAnnotationModelProvider.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.loadProviders(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.access$2(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider$LoadModelsWorkspaceRunnable.run(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.loadModel(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.getMergedModel(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.Web25MergedModelProvider.modify(Web25MergedModelProvider.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.populateDefaultContent(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.createWeb30DeploymentDescriptor(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.execute(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$4.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$5.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: Which Kepler package is this? How did it get installed? Which "web module" facet is it, dynamic or static?

Comment: eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64 is the eclipse version. Its zip file and dynamic module.